# Selenium with Chrome mobile emulator- can't make interactions

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, chromedriver, mobile-automation, emulators

I'm starting to get frustrated with Chrome emulator:
Using JAVA + Selenium + TestNG I'm testing many of our web applications which runs on few browsers. On mobile browser we have a special design - and NOW i'm trying to test it with the Chrome emulator but without great success. I can only load a page and check the elements, BUT I CAN'T click() on it (or other interactions with Actions object).

I've tried a simple :

```
someElement.click()
```

and

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(someElement).click().build().perform();
```

and both doesn't work. The run just stays there until the test case gets time out.

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: Check Prabu's Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error) And if that doesn't work, paste the Exception you're getting.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried most of the ideas in the link you provided (I even start with scrolling to the element I'm testing in each test (using JS- window.scrollBy() ). I do not get any exception, the test just wait until timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `JavascriptExecutor` already? Somtimes I also have the same problem when `WebDriver click()` and `Actions` don't work, then most of the time, `JavascriptExecutor` will do.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", someElement);
```

Hope it helps.